# iOS Objective-C - Selected a row with check mark in UITableView, want to show that selected check mark while updating the previous row

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried this, but i didnt get it. Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:         (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
NSArray *selectedRows=[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    NSMutableArray *rownumberArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *dateArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i<selectedRows.count; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [selectedRows objectAtIndex:i];
        NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
        NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:row];
        [rownumberArray addObject:[HardDependency_IDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [dateArray addObject:[endDateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


        selectedRowArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        dateArray2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        selectedRowArray=rownumberArray;
        dateArray2=dateArray;

 }
```

I am not able to see previously selected rows while updating the `UITableView` cell..

Comment: the code you show has nothing to do with displaying a checkmark.

Comment: i used [hardDependencyTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]; in my table view decleration..i am getting selected index value with check mark..but i cant able to see previously selected rows while editing table view cell data...so can u please....